# Click On Highlighted pencil icon using selenium with c#

Tags: c#, selenium, svg, xpath, webdriverwait

I have tried like this:

```
//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='path' and contains(@d, 'M290.74 93.24l128.02']
```

but it throws exception.

If we use `"//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='path'"` like this, then it's giving all elements but it's not my actual requirement.

Here I posting some pictures, Please some one help me on this. I tried many ways but I didn't make this possible.

[image]

Comment: I did this by selecting the data-prefix as "fas" and It got solved.
Thanks for helping to me.

Answer (score -1):

Try getting the selector by inspecting the element and in the Inspector right click the element and copy the css selector.

[image]

Comment: @Rob this is a picture of the context menu. Not the code, data or error messages. The text has also been typed into the question already. Please explain what the issue is?

Answer (score -1):

The desired element is the only descendent `<path>` element of it's parent `<svg>` element so to `Click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//h5[text()='Brandes Intl Equity']//following::*[name()='svg' and @data-icon='pen'][@role='img']/*[name()='path']"))).Click();
  ```

Answer (score -2):

Try to select icon based on sibling header value

```
"//*[name()='svg' and @data-icon='pen']/*[name()='path']"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I can't decide which one I need click, So I can't use the h5 tag here ```//h5[.='Brandes Intl Equity']```. It was decided based on the grayed out pencil icon.

Comment: @Chenchubabu OK, if you don't want to use `h5` in your XPath, then try `"//*[name()='svg' and @data-icon='pen']/*[name()='path']"`